# Log4J2 StatusLogger messages are not logged in ODL

Tags: log4j2, apache-karaf, opendaylight, pax

I have recently upgraded log4j2 in my application. It is running on top of the open day light controller. The pax-logging-log4j2 (version 1.11.3) bundle is added to the karaf start up bundles. With Log4J2, I have enabled the asynchronous logging as well. The below VM argument is added in the karaf start up script for enabling asynchronous logging.

```
-DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector
-DAsyncLogger.WaitStrategy=Sleep
```

Application logging is working as expected but sometimes, the logs are not in order (timestamps are overlapped). To resolve this, I have tried to set AsyncQueueFullPolicy to ENQUEUE and RingBufferSize to 4098*1024 but no luck.

```
-Dlog4j2.AsyncQueueFullPolicy=Enqueue
-DAysncLogger.RingBufferSize=4194304
```

Tried to enable Log4J2 status logger (as like below) but the logs are not getting logged.

```
status=debug is added the "org.ops4j.apache.pax.logging.cfg" file.
```

Couple of issues, log4j2 status logger is not logged and application logs are not in order.

Any help here would be of great help.

**EDIT:**
Further analysis of the status logger shows asynchronous logging is reverted to synchronous with reason "com.lmax.disruptor.EventFactory cannot be found".

org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [log4j2] WARN : Asynchronous loggers defined, but the disruptor library is not available.  Reverting to synchronous loggers. Ignored FQCN: org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lmax.disruptor.EventFactory cannot be found by org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-log4j2_1.11.3
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:439)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.ops4j.pax.logging.log4j2.internal.PaxLoggingServiceImpl.updated(PaxLoggingServiceImpl.java:263)
        at org.ops4j.pax.logging.log4j2.internal.PaxLoggingServiceImpl$1ManagedPaxLoggingService.updated(PaxLoggingServiceImpl.java:581)
        at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.helper.ManagedServiceTracker.updated(ManagedServiceTracker.java:189)
        at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.helper.ManagedServiceTracker.updateService(ManagedServiceTracker.java:152)
        at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.helper.ManagedServiceTracker.provideConfiguration(ManagedServiceTracker.java:85)
        at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.ConfigurationManager$ManagedServiceUpdate.provide(ConfigurationManager.java:1463)
        at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.ConfigurationManager$ManagedServiceUpdate.run(ConfigurationManager.java:1419)
        at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.UpdateThread.run0(UpdateThread.java:141)
        at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.UpdateThread.run(UpdateThread.java:109)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Added "pax-logging-log4j2-extra" in startup.properties and the dependency issues are resolved.

AsyncLoggerContext is created now.

```
org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [log4j2] DEBUG : Starting LoggerContext[name=pax-logging, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContext@1eb9a021] with configuration org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration@3810215b... Ignored FQCN: org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger
```

but it is not picking the custom AsyncQueueFullPolicy added in the VM argument.

```
-Dlog4j2.AsyncQueueFullPolicy=a.b.c.d.BlockingQueueFullPolicy
```

**Logs:**

```
org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [log4j2] DEBUG : Using DefaultAsyncQueueFullPolicy. Could not create custom AsyncQueueFullPolicy 'a.b.c.d.BlockingQueueFullPolicy': java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fujitsu.fnc.sdnfw.async.BlockingQueueFullPolicy cannot be found by org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api_1.11.3 Ignored FQCN: org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger
```

Created a fragment bundle with the below custom policy and installed it in karaf.

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncQueueFullPolicy;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.EventRoute;

public class BlockingQueueFullPolicy implements AsyncQueueFullPolicy {

    public BlockingQueueFullPolicy() {
        // Don't Delete. Default constructor is required
    }

    @Override
    public EventRoute getRoute(long backgroundThreadId, Level level) {
        return EventRoute.ENQUEUE;
    }

}
```

and pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>a.b.c.d.fw-async-policy-api</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Bundle-Name>Custom Async Queue Full Policy API</Bundle-Name>
                    <Bundle-Vendor>XYZ</Bundle-Vendor>
                    <Bundle-ActivationPolicy>eager</Bundle-ActivationPolicy>
                    <Embed-Transitive>
                        false
                    </Embed-Transitive>
                    <Export-Package>
                        a.b.c.d
                    </Export-Package>
                    <Fragment-Host>system.bundle; extension:=framework</Fragment-Host>
                    <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.slf4j.impl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.slf4j.impl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Which version of pax-logging are you using? I've done major refactoring with version 1.11.x (and 2.0.x) and "status logger" is integrated with default logger of pax-logging itself. and log4j2's "status" logger's level is determined by `org.ops4j.pax.logging.DefaultServiceLog.level` system or context property. Check new [wiki page](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/spaces/paxlogging/pages/499286109/Configuration) for configuration details.

Comment: For "async", you have to set `org.ops4j.pax.logging.log4j2.async` property and ensure that `com.lmax.disruptor.EventFactory` class is available. See [this code fragment](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.logging/blob/logging-1.11.4/pax-logging-log4j2/src/main/java/org/ops4j/pax/logging/log4j2/internal/PaxLoggingServiceImpl.java#L259-L270), though I confess I didn't check asynchronous processing much. Feel free to contribute ;)

Comment: @GrzegorzGrzybek, it is version 1.11.3. I haven't attempted to change this property - org.ops4j.pax.logging.DefaultServiceLog.level. Let me check and get back.

Comment: org.ops4j.pax.logging.log4j2.async=true is set as well

Comment: Setting org.ops4j.pax.logging.DefaultServiceLog.level to DEBUG helps. Any idea how to resolve the logs out of order in asynchronous logging. Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have clear answer now... I didn't have time to check thoroughly the async aspects of Log4j2 in pax logging... But if you provide some sample github project where I can see it (to save me the time to prepare reproducer), I could have a look at it.

Comment: @GrzegorzGrzybek, log event time stamp order issue happens only in a scaled environment. I have to create a sample code to reproduce the issue. Issue here is, log4j2 is not picking the VM argument -Dlog4j2.AsyncQueueFullPolicy=Enqueue
-DAysncLogger.RingBufferSize=4194304. Is there any alternate way to configure these parameters in ODL

Comment: Thanks for hint about these arguments. I can check why they're not passed from sysprops. BTW - do you have LMAX library on your classpath? in bootclasspath? ext?

Comment: @GrzegorzGrzybek, Yes. LMAX disruptor is installed in karaf. I have even tried to add lmax disruptor in startup.properties as well but no help. Added the exception trace in question.

Comment: @GrzegorzGrzybek, sample code to simulate the log out of order is pushed in github - https://github.com/logumohan/log-out-of-order.

Comment: Thanks for the code - checking now.

Comment: Hmm (I had power outage) this project has nothing related to pax-logging and if you think it's a problem (with your code example) then it looks like a problem with Log4j2 itself.